# program received signal “sigabrt”

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am getting program received signal “sigabrt” on main.m

```
- (IBAction)segmentControl:(id)sender {

     NSTimeInterval oneUnit=(60*60*24*3);
     //NSTimeInterval oneUnit1=(60*60*24*60);

     switch (self.ydm.selectedSegmentIndex) {

         case 0:
             for (i=0; i<([forex count]); i++) { //It does not go next step
                 NSTimeInterval x=oneUnit*i/2;
                 i++;
                 id y=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[forex objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]]; 
                  [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:x],@"x",y,@"y", nil]];
                  self.dataForPlot=contentArray;
             }
             break;

         default:
             break;
}
```

Can any one help me ?

Comment: did you tried breakpointing and checking which line it gets SIGBART?

Comment: yes.for(i=0;i<([forex count]); i++) from this it directly goes to return UIApplicationMain(argc,argv,nil,NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])) and shows the sigbrat error

Comment: @Priya, How do you create the array *forex*?

Comment: @Priya - can you tell us what (if anything) is shown in the console? My guess is there's an exception being thrown and you'll see details about it in there.

Comment: Are you sure that contentArray is `NSMutableArray`, not `NSArray`?

Comment: @EmptyStack forex=[(NSString *)[Global soapResults] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is because of ***forex***. It seems it is autoreleased. Make sure it is available at the time you access it. You should *retain* it while you create it.

***Edit after the comments on the question:***

Just change the line,

```
forex=[(NSString *)[Global soapResults] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

to be like this,

```
forex=[[(NSString *)[Global soapResults] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Update : Try this first

Change

```
case 0:
         for (i=0; i<([forex count]); i++) { //It does not go next step
```

to

```
   case 0:
      if(!forex)
       {
          NSLog(@"Here is my Error");
         for (i=0; i<([forex count]); i++) { //It does not go next step
```

if you get the NSLog ..that's it no forex.

**Change**

```
for (i=0; i<([forex count]); i++)
```

**to**

```
for (int i=0; i<([forex count]); i++)
```

and Try Again.. :D

Comment: If it was that, then it wouldn't compile let alone run. Although I have no idea where `i` is being declared in their code.

Comment: yeah...i know...but still ..only two problems can be there..i posted answer for one,,and empty stack posted for other..let's see who is right??:D

Comment: I don't think *the missing int* is the problem here, as it seems that @Priya typed the code here, not copied from her project.

Comment: @Shubhank - But that *can't* be a problem as he's getting a SIGABRT. So we know the app has compiled properly and is being run.

Comment: well..i guess you are right...i hope now no one down votes me.

Comment: @Shubhank, Ha ha! You better update your answer with a actual solution before someone else comes and downvotes your answer! :-)